# Antivirus for Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, software-rec, anti-virus

Looking for Antivirus software under Windows7, which will not be installed as service and won't start at boot, but just will scan files downloaded in Firefox. I understand that Firefox is using antivirus software registered with Windows. However, most of the antivirus software will just install residentially into memory and slow down operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [Fireclam](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10882/):

> Use ClamAV to scan Firefox downloads
>   for viruses. Every download will
>   automatically be scanned in the
>   background. An alert message is shown
>   if a virus is found. Works on Linux,
>   MacOS X (requires ClamAV) and Windows
>   (requires ClamWin).

This requires a **local** installation of Clam AntiVirus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is exactly what you need but [Dr.Web anti-virus link checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/938/) addon for Firefox can help. This plugin allows you to check any file you are about to download, any page you are about to visit with online version of Dr.Web anti-virus.

Comment: This is good, but will slow down the process since should be also uploaded to their server. I still prefer solution which will scan locally. Thanks anyway!